# C# Editing parameters of user objects in listBox

Tags: c#, object, parameters, listbox, edit

How can I edit parameters of my objects added to ListBox?

Already I have something like this:

```
public class Car
{
    protected double aa;
    protected string n;

    public Car(double aa, string n)
    {
        this.a = aa;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public virtual double Speed()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public class Car111 : Car
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Car111(double aa, string n)
            : base(aa, n)
        {
            A = aa;
            Name = n;
        }

        public class Car222 : Car
        {
            public double A { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Car111(double a, string n)
            : base(aa, n)
            {
                A = aa;
                Name = n;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }

            listBox1.Items.Add(new Car111(aa, "MyCar")); //add obcject to listbox
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Car111(aa, "MyCar")); //add obcject to listbox

            private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Car111 item = (Car111)listBox1.SelectedItem;

                if (item != null)
                    item.A = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);  //There is a problem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A don't know what to do to change "aa" parameter in Car111 and Car222 class. How can I add the summary Speed of Cars being adding to listbox?

Comment: This is quite confusing, I'd suggest getting better variable names than `aa` and `n`.  You dont set speed in any location, so it would never be more than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question and the fact that the code you have provided doesn't compile makes it a bit more difficult, however I'll take a stab at it...  There are 2 things I can think of that you may be asking/having trouble with

FIRST

Let's start with the end of your post:

> A don't know what to do to change "aa" parameter in Car111 and Car222
>   class. How can I add the summary Speed of Cars being adding to
>   listbox?

I don't see anything in your code that refers to speed, other than a virtual method that always returns 0.  Based on the context of your question, however, I'm guessing that perhaps you are using `aa` from the base object, `Car`.  Next, I'd like to look at your last line of code:

```
item.A = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);  //There is a problem
```

Note that you are not setting `aa` here, you are setting `A`.  If you are trying to expose `aa` with `A`, then instead of declaring `A` as

```
public double A { get; set; }
```

you would instead need to do this:

```
public double A { get{return aa;} set{aa = value;} }
```

The reason for this is because when you use auto-properties, the compiler creates a backing variable in the background for you; obviously, it isn't going to know that you want it to be backed with `aa` (or anything else) unless you tell it so.  Note that this applies to `n` and `Name`, too.

While we are on the topic, if all of your derived classes are going to have an `A` and `Name` the expose `aa` and `n`, respectively, then you might as well put them in the parent class.

---

SECOND

Looking at the first line of your question:

> How can I edit parameters of my objects added to ListBox?

I think you are saying that you want the listbox to show a new value.  If that is the case, I would question how you are displaying your car data in the listbox.  When you execute line of your code,

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new Car111(aa, "MyCar")); //add obcject to listbox
```

The listbox would add an item, but unless there is some work going on that you are not showing us, then what would show up is `<yourAssemblyName>.Car111` (unless Car111 is also supposed to have a `ToString` like Car222, in which case you would show the name, "MyCar".)
Either way, when you call

```
item.A = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);  //There is a problem
```

That isn't going to update anything your listbox is showing.

---

Suggestion:
I don't see anything in your example that necessitates the added complexity of inheritance.  Perhaps there is more that you are not showing, but based on what you have here, and based on the assumptions I have made, I would refactor your code to look something like this:

```
public class Car
{
    //update aa, n, and A to reflect what they represent.
    //I'm guessing that n represents "name" and "aa" represents "speed"
    //Unless you need inheritance, you can use private instead of protected
    private double _speed;
    private string _name;

    //I'm guessing "A" represents "Speed".
    public double Speed
    {
        get { return _speed; }
        set { _speed = value; }
    }
    //This was in your base class, but you don't need it if
    // "Speed" (what was "A") will work up here
    //public virtual double Speed()
    //{
    //  return 0;
    //}

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    //parameters should reflect what they represent, as well
    public Car(double speed, string name)
    {
        this._speed = speed;
        this._name = name;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return Name;
        //If you want to show the name and the speed in the listbox
        //you could use the following:
        return string.Format("{0} is going {1}", Name, Speed);
    }
}
```

Then you can add it the way you were, except w/o inheritance (unless needed):

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new Car(travelingSpeed, "MyCar")); //add object to listbox
listBox1.Items.Add(new Car(travelingSpeed, "MyCar")); //add object to listbox
```

Finally, unless you have data binding going on, if you simply update the object, the listbox won't update.  You will need to tell the  listbox to update.  Here is one way to do that:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Car c = (Car)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    if (c == null)
        return;

    if (!Double.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out c.Speed))
        return;
    int idx = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    listBox1.Items.Insert(idx, c);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the problem is more complicated. I must change the parameters of the object which are already added to listBox. For example change parameter aa of Car111

Comment: `Car c = (Car)listBox1.SelectedItem;` pulls the item from the list box.  `Double.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out c.Speed)` updates that value of the item. You have made it this far, but you still need to update the listbox to reflect these changes. The last 3 lines of my example will do that for you by removing the old item and inserting the updated item into the old spot. The end experience is the same as if you edit the listbox item directly. If you want the listbox to update automatically when you edit the underlying item, you'll need to look at databinding.